# "rails plugin install git://github.com/thorny-sun/prawnto.git" is not working in rails 3.0.6

Tags: prawn, prawnto

I want to install prawnto plug-in in my rails 3.0.6 application but when i fire the command as given here

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/thorny-sun/prawnto.git
```

it gives me result as given below

```
mkdir -p /var/www/octo11/vendor/plugins/prawnto
rm -rf /var/www/octo11/vendor/plugins/prawnto
```

which create and delete plugin directory automatically

Please anyone suggest me any alternatively to install the prawnto plugin. My system configuration is as given below

```
rails 3.0.6
ruby 1.8.7
ubuntu 11.04
```

Comment: asking for help with conflicting versions of rails - 3.1 and 3.0.6. which is it?

Answer (score 1):

thorny-sun seems to have deleted their fork, try one with recent updates, including docs on using with 3.1 in the readme:

https://github.com/forrest/prawnto

The best way to install seems to be using the gem version of this fork:

```
gem "prawnto_2", :require => "prawnto"
```

and then

`bundle install`

Comment: Thanks for your solution as its working nicely but to add gem prawnto_2 i need to update all gems as this is for rails 3.1 and if i am updating my gems it causes version issue. So please provide me alternative of PRAWN

Comment: You need to edit your question, as it specifically starts by asking for help with a rails 3.1 application, and then you later say it is Rails 3.0.6 - which is it?